# inserting if select returns a row

Tags: php, sql-server, select, insert

USING MS SQL-SERVER

I wanted to know if it was possible or better said the most efficient way to insert values into a table where one of the values inserted is dependent on another table, and if that Select query is not existent on the other table it would not do it.

for example the next query

```
INSERT INTO producto VALUES 
('ad-101', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2016','aer3457','1',(SELECT Id from Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161017293')),
('ad-102', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2015','aer5647','1',(SELECT Id from Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161019329'))
```

If `5161019329` was not on the table Invetory only 1 row was inserted.

i know i can always do a seperate query for the select part and afterwards do my logic on php to insert it or not, but that's not that efficent since sometimes i can have 100 rows inserted at once.

Thanks,

Comment: Use a foreign key constraint on that column and see if your query was successful.

Answer (score 0):

If the column that ID number your select returns is not a nullable column mysql should prevent the insert and throw an error.

Comment: Im using SQL-server as the tags say, need to specify in post, sorry. if the select returns no row i will get a NULL and will insert with null

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question I thought you wanted to not insert if that query returned null.

Comment: yes indeed, but before hand the value might be a NULL, so i need to allow NULLs

Comment: How does this query string get built? Some php logic based on input from users I take it?

Comment: yes, from a file that is uploaded it gets converted into json and passed in a form.

Comment: I might suggest then that the logic make the determination through the use of that same query add to if the string even gets built.

Comment: As to* if the string gets built.

Comment: that is exactly what my initial post is about, i know that can be made, but if im inserting 100 lines, im not sure that would be efficient.

Comment: Probably more efficient since either way you have to make that sub query. Using it to determine if you construct that portion of the concatenated query string rather than constructing everything including stuff you don't want seems less efficient. Is the serie  column an index on that table? If so those sub queries should return very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query, it should work

```
INSERT INTO producto
SELECT
'ad-101', '27', 'Nissan','NP300','2016','aer3457','1', Id FROM Inventario WHERE Serie = '5161017293'
```

If there is no row in `Incentario` with `Serie` 5161017293, no data will be inserted.

Answer (score -1):

PDO has a rowCount() function that can be called to count the amount of rows that the query you have made has, if that is what you mean. (The question didn't really make sense)

You could try:

```
$query = $handler->query("Your select query");

if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
  // Insert Query
}
```

Other than that I haven't used the MySQLi connection much but you could loop the query with a `$count++` variable started at 0, then if that `$count` variable is equal to 0 then insert the query later on in the logic.

Sorry if the answer doesn't make sense but the question didn't either.

Comment: i think u misunderstood, might have been a bad explaination but you can see that inside the INSERT query there is a SELECT sub query, where the select query might be empty but yet the insert would take place, since the column accepts NULLs, and i need it to accept NULLs.